# making number of rows for grouped-by coumn identical (align number of observations)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3],
                    'date': ['2018-01-01 10:00', '2018-01-01 10:00', '2018-01-01 11:00',
                             '2018-01-01 11:00', '2018-01-01 12:00', '2018-01-01 12:00']})
data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
```

output:

```
    date                   id
0   2018-01-01 10:00:00     1
1   2018-01-01 10:00:00     3
2   2018-01-01 11:00:00     1
3   2018-01-01 11:00:00     2
4   2018-01-01 12:00:00     1
5   2018-01-01 12:00:00     3
```

For each id there are three possible observation points. However, not every id is present at every point. I want transform the data such that all ids have the same number of observations. There should be an additional var indicating whether the observation was originally empty or not. My desired output would be this:

```
    date                   id   empty_obs
0   2018-01-01 10:00:00     1   0
1   2018-01-01 10:00:00     2   1
2   2018-01-01 10:00:00     3   0
3   2018-01-01 11:00:00     1   0
4   2018-01-01 11:00:00     2   0
5   2018-01-01 11:00:00     3   1
6   2018-01-01 12:00:00     1   0
7   2018-01-01 12:00:00     2   1
8   2018-01-01 12:00:00     3   0
```

My only idea at the moment is to create a DateRange like this:

```
period = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(data.date.min(), periods=3, freq='H' ))
```

and then somehow merge this with a grouped-by version of data. However, this seems not possible.

I'm sure there is a simple solution out there. I'd appreciate any hints towards it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
data.assign(empty_obs=0).set_index(['date','id']).unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(1).reset_index()
Out[73]: 
                 date  id empty_obs
0 2018-01-01 10:00:00   1    0.0
1 2018-01-01 10:00:00   2    1.0
2 2018-01-01 10:00:00   3    0.0
3 2018-01-01 11:00:00   1    0.0
4 2018-01-01 11:00:00   2    0.0
5 2018-01-01 11:00:00   3    1.0
6 2018-01-01 12:00:00   1    0.0
7 2018-01-01 12:00:00   2    1.0
8 2018-01-01 12:00:00   3    0.0
```

Comment: You can bypass fillna for a more performant answer: `data.set_index(['date', 'id']).assign(empty_obs=1).unstack(-1, fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , that is great improvement :-)

Comment: Added something similar with groupby. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `groupby` + `size` followed by the `unstack`/`stack` idiom demonstrated by @Wen:

```
data.groupby(['date', 'id'])\
    .size()\
    .unstack(fill_value=0)\
    .stack()\
    .reset_index(name='empty_obs')

                 date  id  empty_obs
0 2018-01-01 10:00:00   1          1
1 2018-01-01 10:00:00   2          0
2 2018-01-01 10:00:00   3          1
3 2018-01-01 11:00:00   1          1
4 2018-01-01 11:00:00   2          1
5 2018-01-01 11:00:00   3          0
6 2018-01-01 12:00:00   1          1
7 2018-01-01 12:00:00   2          0
8 2018-01-01 12:00:00   3          1
```